# Left (right) invariant vector fields on superspace

Tags: supersymmetry, lie-algebra

I read Freed'd book on "Five lectures on supersymmetry". For any vector space $V$ with metric of signature $(1,n-1)$ he constructs super Lie algebra
$$
L=V \oplus S^*,
$$
where $S$ is space of Majorana spinors. Bracket in basis $Q_a$ for $S$ and $P_\mu$ for $V$ is given by
$$
[Q_a, Q_b]=-2\Gamma_{ab}^\mu P_\mu.
$$

Then he claims that on corresponding super Lie group a basis of left invariant vector fields is given by $(\partial_\mu, D_a)$, where
$$
D_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^a} - \Gamma_{ab}^\mu \theta^b \partial_\mu.
$$

My question is how to find such a basis starting from the first principals?

I was trying to do the following. On a Lie group $G$, if I denote left action $L_g(x)=gx$ then condition for a vector field $D$ to be left invariant is $((L_g)_*D)(x)=D(gx)$. My problem is that I don't understand how to write explicitly this condition for this super Lie group. If we have such condition it provides a system of equation for components of left invariant vector fields and then solving this system we can find a basis.

Comment: I think I recall seeing a derivation in Becker, Becker and Schwarz.

Comment: The $D_a$ anticommute with the $Q_a$, and so transform a superfield into an other superfield. $\delta_ξD_aφ(z) = D_aδ_ξφ(z) = iD_a(ξQ + \barξ \bar Q)φ(z) = i(ξQ + \barξ \bar Q) D_aφ(z)$ .
So they are supercovariant derivatives.